# iOS multi line title bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have tried all the answers posted here regarding this and I have achieved multiple lines but I need the text to start a little from above from where it is right now.
Please see the screen shot it shows where I want the title label to start from.

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/23jl4jk.png]

Here is my code -

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
[titleLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:30.0]];
[titleLabel setText:@"LET'S GET YOU REGISTERED"];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

I have tried replacing the label with a UIView but still no luck.

The code in my custom nav controller file is -

```
@interface UINavigationBar (myNave)
- (CGSize)changeHeight:(CGSize)size;
@end

@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height * 0.15;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth,screenHeight);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `titleLabel` in the visual editor?

Comment: How about changing the text to simply "Register". That will fit on one line.

Comment: The title label is not there in the IB. It has to be added programmatically since i am using a custom nav bar and i need that string there cannot change it

Comment: Please note the edit I have applied only makes it so the screenshot is visible here on StackOverflow, rather than forcing those who wish to see it to go elsewhere.  Please refresh your view of the question if you have further edits to make.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I couldn't add image here since i did not have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just set the numberOfLines to fit whatever the text length is. You can do this by setting the number of lines to zero. Also, a size 30 font will not allow for multi-line text to fit in a UINavigationItem (without sizeToFit). You may consider setting the UINavigationBar to be clear and creating your own titleView to fit at the top of the screen if you need it to be size 30.

However, something similar to this will give you a multiline text that fits perfectly inside the nav:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width-100, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleView.frame.size.width, titleView.frame.size.height)];
[titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0]];
[titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

NSString *titleString = @"This is a\n multiline string";
[titleLabel setText:titleString];

[titleView addSubview:titleLabel];

[self.navigationController.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
```

Comment: Had to make a few changes but finally worked. Thank you for the ans :)